# Why is my recursive function is not concatenatening string?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, string-formatting

I am writing a recursive function to print a string backwards. I am wondering why my string formatting of the return statement is not working? I am using python 3.7.
It would be very helpful if someone please can tell me why I can not write a recursive function like following?

```
def back(word):

    if len(word)>1:

        print (word[-1] + (back(word[:len(word)-1])), end="")
    elif len(word)==1:
        return word
    else:
        print ("end")


back("stack")
```

Comment: Printing and returning are different things. Your function only returns anything when it gets a string of length 1. Otherwise it prints something instead of returning it.

Comment: Do you need to use a recursive function? The simplest way to reverse a string is `print(word[::-1])`

Comment: Yes, I am using a recursive function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *khelwood* mentioned in the comments, doing a `print()` is not a substitute for `return`.

The fix for your problem is:

```py
def back(word):
    ln = len(word)
    if ln >1:
        wmo = word[-1]
        # Changed print() to return
        return (wmo + (back(word[:len(word)-1])))
    elif ln ==1:
        return word
    else:
        print ("end")

# Changed to print() the returned values from function 
print(back("stack"))
```

As you can see above, in the fixed solution, we are *returning* the value from function and printing it outside.

Hope this helps!